# Spanish equivalent of "anglicanizar"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

How do you say in Spanish "to make a foreign word sound Spanish". The equivalent of "to anglicize" but for Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

To say "to make a foreign word sound Spanish", we use "españolizar".

De la DRAE

> **[españolizar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GUtvDOh&o=h)**
>
> 1. tr. Dar carácter español a algo o a alguien. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. **Dar forma española a un vocablo o expresión de otro idioma.** U. t. c. prnl.

Comment: También se puede usar *hispanizar* y *castellanizar*

Comment: Buena respuesta, sí sumamos el comentario de guifa aun más.

Comment: @Fedorqui buena edición, mejora la respuesta. Good editing, it improves the answer.